# TF30225: Error uploading report 'Sprint Burndown':

Tags: tfs, ssrs-2008

We are trying to create a new TFS Team Project, but we're encountering the following error.

```
Exception Message: The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified.
```

I've tried changing every aspect of the TFS Report Source, but nothing appears to work.

I've also tried setting the Execution account (even to admin) and setting no user required.

However, nothing works.

Thoughts?